# Convert image to the HEIF format on Windows

Tags: windows, heif

I want to take advantage of HEIF's benefits on Windows. I feel I've done quite a bit of searching and I find a lot about opening HEIF files on Windows and converting from HEIF to JPG. I can't find anything about converting a popular lossless type (BMP, PNG, GIF) to a HEIF.

Is there a library (or available application) that can convert from a popular lossless type to HEIF on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Imaging Component (WIC) API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-api) comes with Microsoft HEIF Encoder in latest Windows 10. That is, you can use the API for image encoding.

```
### Microsoft HEIF Encoder

 * Class Identifier: CLSID_WICHeifEncoder
 * Signing Status: WICComponentSigned
 * Author: Microsoft
 * Vendor Identifier: {F0E749CA-EDEF-4589-A73A-EE0E626A2A2B}
 * Version: 1.0.0.0
 * Spec Version: 1.0.0.0
 * Friendly Name: Microsoft HEIF Encoder
 * IWICBitmapCodecInfo:
  * Container Format: GUID_ContainerFormatHeif
  * Pixel Formats: GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGR
  * Color Management Version: 1.0.0.0
  * MIME Types: image/heic,image/heif
  * File Extensions: .heic,.heif
 * IWICBitmapEncoderInfo
```

You might need to install [HEIF Image Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/heif-image-extensions/9pmmsr1cgpwg?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) from Store to enable format support.